# How to make a d-link dwa-123 wireless n 150 work on ubuntu 13.10 (saucy)

Tags: wireless

I recently installed saucy as part of a dualboot setup.
My laptop's internal network adaptor is shot and so I have to use an external D-Link DWA-123.
I have the installation disc and everything and it works perfectly on windows.
However, I cannot get it to work on Ubuntu. How can I go about doing so?

My `lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 003: ID 0cf3:311d Atheros Communications, Inc.
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0c45:6458 Microdia
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 0955:7100 NVidia Corp. Notion Ink Adam
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 2001:3310 D-Link Corp.
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: There are several revisions of this device. Please edit your question to add the result of the terminal command: lsusb

Comment: Install `usbutils` and paste the output of `usb-devices` into your post.

Answer (score 6):

Type the following code in the console:

```
sudo apt-get install git build-essential
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8188eu.git
cd rtl8188eu
make all
sudo make install
```

Then remove previously manual installed modules:
 **eg:- sudo modprobe -r rtl8192cu**

```
sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

Unplug , re-plug you should get going.

**Tested on Dlink DWA-123  rev D1**
Speedtest results : http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/3477686124

Comment: +1 Thanks. This worked on my Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca (Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS)!

Answer (score 0):

Open a terminal (press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) and type the following command

```
rfkill list all
```

This will list the available wireless devices. Typing

```
rfkill unblock all
```

will unblock all wireless devices and

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

will bring device `wlan0` up i.e. initialize the device and try to connect to the network using the current settings (assuming your wireless device is wlan0). For more information on the rfkill command you can type

`man rfkill`

to read the man page. (press <kbd>q</kbd> at any time to return to command shell)

If that doesn't help, install ceni

Answer (score 0):

Your device seems to be recognized, plus the vendor of dwa-123 is actually RALINK. So maybe these instructions do work for you:

Check if kernel driver is loaded.

```
$ lsmod | grep rt2800usb
```

If the driver is not present load em:

```
$ sudo modprobe rt2800usb
```

To make changes permanent add

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "rt2800usb" >> /etc/modules'
```

@see:

- [Re: [SOLVED] Wireless adapter driver for D-Link DWA-123](https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=7283#p34018)
- [rt2800usb - Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/rt2800usb)

Comment: This didn't work. Everytime i run the command ""rt2800usb" >> /etc/modules'" it returns permission denied

Comment: Well /etc/modules is accessible by root only. Try `sudo nano` and then add _rt2800usb_ at the end of the file.

Comment: I don't understand this... I tried sudo nano and it opens a blank file. What am I to put in it?

Comment: You can find more information here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Loadable_Modules#Using_loadable_modules

Comment: rt2800usb must be put at the end of this file.