# MediaTek MT7630 not working on Ubuntu 14.04 (need alternatives)

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, usb, asus

Please help :/

I have an ASUS x550c laptop with a MediaTek MT7630e wifi card. The wired internet works, but wireless doesn't. I have tried all the online solutions and none of them work. Since I need this laptop for work I am very close to giving up and going back to Windows :/

I've also seen this bug, doesn't give me encouragement that it's been sitting unresolved like this for the last 9 months:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1220146

What I am asking for here:

1. Are there any news on this bug or is there anybody that has a similar setup
   that managed to get wireless working on their laptop?
2. Is there an alternative, like a WiFi USB stick or an adapter that
   can be plugged in into the ethernet port (and that works with Ubuntu)? I am willing to try
   anything as long as it doesn't entail having access to routers (I am
   imagining a scenario in a hotel where this is not possible)
3. Is there a Linux distro that would work with this setup/card? (not sure if this is ok to ask here but I am desperate)

A few symptoms:

- "rfkill list all" doesn't show anything after I did the first answer from here:
  [How to make a d-link dwa-123 wireless n 150 work on ubuntu 13.10 (saucy)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413027/how-to-make-a-d-link-dwa-123-wireless-n-150-work-on-ubuntu-13-10-saucy)
- I bought this USB stick:
  http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_ss_i_0_14?url=search-alias%3Delectronics&field-keywords=linux%20usb%20wifi%20adapters&sprefix=linux+usb+wifi%2Celectronics%2C208
  and since it doesn't have Linux drivers (Hardware B1) I downloaded
  ndiswrapper and tried installing XP drivers through that - didn't
  work.
- Fn+F2 button doesn't work, WiFi lamp doesn't turn on

Thanks for your time!!

Comment: maybe this page can help you, I worked my http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2181558

Comment: I managed to solve everything by runnign the commands from the last answer here: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=53&t=153544 Thanks for the help!